# Fixed thermal Trip vs fixed magnetic trip current ratings

Tags: power, protection

I am looking into a series of 2 pole circuit breakers (Sprecher + schuh 's series KTU7 UL489 molded case circuit breakers) and they seems to have 2 ratings, a thermal trip rating and a magnetic trip rating. What is the difference between these two ratings? Is the magnetic trip rating the same as the instantaneous trip rating?

Comment: You might add a link to what you are asking about.  It does sound like magnetic might be fast and thermal slower.

Comment: Yes you're right, I confirmed this with the manufacturer. Thermal is slower. Magnetic, also known as the instantaneous trip current rating which is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thermal setting is a **thermal overload** protection. It has a time-delayed response. The heavier the overload, the faster it trips. It may be implemented by something like a bimetallic strip.

The magnetic setting is **instantaneous short-circuit protection**. It has no intentional delay. It may be implemented by something like a solenoid plunger, restrained by a spring.

Here is an illustration of a typical time-current curve  for a miniature circuit breaker (Clipsal 4 series) showing the thermal and magnetic trip characteristics. Note the thermal trip takes a long time - minutes or seconds - while the magnetic trip responds in 10ms or less.

[image]